# Base estimator meaning in the context of Isolation forest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am struggling to understand the meaning of "Base estimator" in the context of Isolation Forest.

One of the parameters for Isolation Forest method in scikit-learn is `n_estimators`; its description in [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) states the following:

> The number of base estimators in the ensemble.

I tried interpreting the documentation on Sklearn and stuff on Google and Youtube
to understand this terminology but no luck. Could someone please explain what it means in the context of IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: it is the special kind of decision tree called **Isolation Tree (iTree)** in the [original paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest):

> We show in this paper that a tree structure can be constructed effectively to isolate every single instance. [...] This isolation characteristic of tree forms the basis of our method to detect anomalies, and we call this tree Isolation Tree or iTree.
>
> The proposed method, called Isolation Forest or iForest, builds an ensemble of iTrees for a given data set [...]

---

All ensemble methods (to which Isolation Forest [belongs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble)) consist of base estimators (i.e. they are exactly *ensembles of base estimators*); from the [sklearn guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html):

> The goal of **ensemble methods** is to combine the predictions of several **base estimators** built with a given learning algorithm in order to improve generalizability / robustness over a single estimator.

For example, in [Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) (which arguably was the inspiration for the name Isolation Forest), this base estimator is a simple decision tree:

> **n_estimators : *int, default=100***
>
> The number of trees in the forest.

Similarly for algorithms like [Gradient Boosting Trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor) (despite the scikit-learn docs referring to them as "*boosting stages*", they are decision trees nevertheless), [Extra Trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier) etc.

In all these algorithms, the base estimator is fixed (although its specific parameters can vary as set in the ensemble arguments). There is another category of ensemble methods, where the exact model to be used as base estimator can be also set by a respective argument `base_estimator`; for example, here is the [Bagging Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier):

> **base_estimator : *object, default=None***
>
> The base estimator to fit on random subsets of the dataset. If None, then the base estimator is a decision tree.

and [AdaBoost](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier):

> **base_estimator : *object, default=None***
>
> The base estimator from which the boosted ensemble is built. [...]  If None, then the base estimator is `DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)`.

Historically speaking, the first ensembles were built using various versions of decision trees, and arguably still today it is decision trees (or variants, like iTrees) that are almost exclusively used for such ensembles; quoting from another answer of mine in [Execution time of AdaBoost with SVM base classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968476/execution-time-of-adaboost-with-svm-base-classifier/57982983#57982983) :

> Adaboost (and similar ensemble methods) were conceived using decision trees as base classifiers (more specifically, decision *stumps*, i.e. DTs with a depth of only 1); there is good reason why still today, if you don't specify explicitly the `base_classifier` argument, it assumes a value of `DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)`. DTs are suitable for such ensembling because they are essentially **unstable** classifiers, which is not the case with SVMs, hence the latter are not expected to offer much when used as base classifiers.