# using random forest as base classifier with adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, adaboost

Can I use AdaBoost with random forest as a base classifier? I searched on the internet and I didn't find anyone who does it.

Like in the following code; I try to run it but it takes a lot of time:

```py
estimators = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
                       ('transformer', TfidfTransformer()),
                       ('classifier', AdaBoostClassifier(learning_rate=1))])

RF=RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy',n_estimators=100,max_depth=500,min_samples_split=100,max_leaf_nodes=None,
                          max_features='log2')


param_grid={
    'vectorizer__ngram_range': [(1,2),(1,3)],
    'vectorizer__min_df': [5],
    'vectorizer__max_df': [0.7],
    'vectorizer__max_features': [1500],

    'transformer__use_idf': [True , False],
    'transformer__norm': ('l1','l2'),
    'transformer__smooth_idf': [True , False],
     'transformer__sublinear_tf': [True , False],

    'classifier__base_estimator':[RF],
    'classifier__algorithm': ("SAMME.R","SAMME"),
    'classifier__n_estimators':[4,7,11,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,43,50]
}
```

I tried with the GridSearchCV, I added the RF classifier into the AdaBoost parameters.
if I use it would the accuracy increase?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No wonder you have not actually seen anyone doing it - it is an absurd and bad idea.

You are trying to build an ensemble (Adaboost) which in itself consists of ensemble base classifiers (RFs) - essentially an "ensemble-squared"; so, no wonder about the high computation time.

But even if it was practical, there are good *theoretical* reasons *not* to do it; quoting from my own answer in [Execution time of AdaBoost with SVM base classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968476/execution-time-of-adaboost-with-svm-base-classifier/57982983#57982983):

> Adaboost (and similar ensemble methods) were conceived using decision trees as base classifiers (more specifically, decision *stumps*, i.e. DTs with a depth of only 1); there is good reason why still today, if you don't specify explicitly the `base_classifier` argument, it assumes a value of `DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)`. DTs are suitable for such ensembling because they are essentially **unstable** classifiers, which is not the case with SVMs, hence the latter are not expected to offer much when used as base classifiers.
>
> On top of this, SVMs are computationally much more expensive than decision trees (let alone decision *stumps*), which is the reason for the long processing times you have observed.

The argument holds for RFs, too - they are not *unstable* classifiers, hence there is not any reason to actually expect performance improvements when using them as base classifiers for boosting algorithms, like Adaboost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Random Forest can be used as a base classifier of AdaBoost Classifier. Here is the link of one such model used in a research paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339978251_A_Precise_Breast_Cancer_Detection_Approach_Using_Ensemble_of_Random_Forest_with_AdaBoost). In this paper authors have got improved accuracies than past literatures.
If you search you will find some other research papers using similar type of models.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:
It's not impossible.
I don't know if there's anything wrong with doing so in theory, but I tried this once and the accuracy increased.

Long answer:

I tried it on a typical dataset with n rows of p real-valued features, and a label list of length n. In case it matters, they are embeddings of nodes in a graph obtained by the DeepWalk algorithm, and the nodes are categorized into two classes. I trained a few classification models on this data using 5-fold cross validation, and measured common evaluation metrics for them (precision, recall, AUC etc.). The models I have used are SVM, logistic regression, random Forest, 2-layer perceptron and Adaboost with random forest classifiers. The last model, Adaboost with random forest classifiers, yielded the best results (95% AUC compared to multilayer perceptron's 89% and random forest's 88%). Sure, now the runtime has increased by a factor of, let's say, 100, but it's still about 20 mins, so it's not a constraint to me.

Here's what I thought: Firstly, I'm using cross validation, so there's probably no overfitting flying under the radar. Secondly, both are ensemble learning methods, but random forest is a bagging method, wheras Adaboost is a boosting technique. Perhaps they're still different enough for their combination to make sense?