# Use Adaboost with random forest base classifiers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-learning, adaboost

Does anyone know whether one could use Adaboost with random forest base classifiers? I searched the web to learn more about this, but most webpages provided comparisons of the two as ensemble learning methods, and I didn't find anything about using them together.

(Basically somebody asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977025/using-random-forest-as-base-classifier-with-adaboost), but the only answer so far contradicts with my observations, which I'm sharing below)

Notwithstanding, nobody explicitly said there was anything wrong with it, so I tried it on a typical dataset with n rows of p real-valued features, and a label list of length n. In case it matters, they are embeddings of nodes in a graph obtained by the DeepWalk algorithm, and the nodes are categorized into two classes. I trained a few classification models on this data using 5-fold cross validation, and measured common evaluation metrics for them (precision, recall, AUC etc.). The models I have used are SVM, logistic regression, random Forest, 2-layer perceptron and Adaboost with random forest classifiers. The last model, Adaboost with random forest classifiers, yielded the best results. Sure, now the runtime has increased by a factor of, let's say, 100, but it's still about 20 mins, so it's not a constraint to me. Now I wonder if I should be suspicious about its good accuracy (95% AUC compared to multilayer perceptron's 89% and random forest's 88%)

Here's what I thought: Firstly, I'm using cross validation, so there's probably no overfitting flying under the radar. Secondly, both are ensemble learning methods, but random forest is a bagging method, wheras Adaboost is a boosting technique. So they're still different enough for their combination to make sense.

Am I wrong?

Comment: "*nobody explicitly said there was anything wrong with it*" - that's not true, I have explicitly explain in the linked answer that, at least **in theory**, Adaboost should be applied to *unstable* classifiers, which RF is not. Now, keep in mind that ML is largely an *empirical*, theory-poor domain, and the fact that in your case, with the specific data, you get better results is not a contradiction. In any case, this is not a *programming* question - see the NOTE here for alternative places to ask it: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Notice also that AUC is *not* accuracy, neither it measures the performance of a *single* final model (it measures the performance of a model averaged across the range of all possible *classification thresholds*); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58612125/4685471

Comment: I'm aware that AUC is not accuracy, but that was what we were mainly interested in (because it's a better metric when using imbalanced data). Let me add accuracy numbers here: Adaboost with RF: 90.5, RF: 88.5, multilayer perceptron:86% (average over 5 folds)

Comment: Arguably, for imbalanced data you should check the F1 score (accuracy is indeed meaningless). The mentioned issues with AUC hold.