# How can i combine xgboost with adaboost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, adaboost

I have combined random forest with adaboost as

```
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=10, base_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,max_depth=20))
```

now i want to combine adaboost with xgboost and i have tried like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=XGBClassifier(eval_metric='mlogloss'))
```

and it is not working correctly. How to do this?

Comment: This is not a good idea (regardless of whatever error you get here) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968476/execution-time-of-adaboost-with-svm-base-classifier and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977025/using-random-forest-as-base-classifier-with-adaboost

Answer (score -1):

use would just use it like this

import lib1, lib2, lib3, lib4, lib5

Comment: no, it's not the syntax error, it is some sort of a logical error.

Comment: @JamalAhmed "*Some sort of logical error*" is not enough; please post the full error - see how to create a [mre]